# Email not being sent and there is no error [SAS]

Tags: email, parameters, sas

```
%let emailUsername =        %scan(&sysparm,1,+);
%let email =                %unquote(%str(&emailUsername.@example.com));
%let sasProgram =           %scan(&sysparm,2,+);
%let todayDate = %sysfunc(today(),MMDDYYS10.);
%let timeNow = %sysfunc(time(),TIMEAMPM.);

FILENAME mail
    EMAIL TO=%unquote(%str(%'&email.%'))
    SUBJECT='SAS Job Complete: &todayDate. on &timeNow.' 
    CONTENT_TYPE="text/html";



DATA _NULL_;
    file mail;
    PUT "<body>";
    PUT "<p>Hello,</p>";
    PUT "<p>This is an email confirming that your SAS program [&sasProgram..sas] has successfully ran and finished.</p>";
    PUT "<p>- Creators of the SAS Program</p>";
    PUT "</body>";
Run;
```

I am trying to understand why an email is not being sent. **If I hard code the email address in, it works** but when I have variables passed through it doesn't work. There is no error in the log file in regards to me trying to send an email so I am assuming it was successful.

Is there something else I need to do or look at?

Comment: If you add `%put %unquote(%str(%'&email.%'));` before the filename statement, does the log show you the email address you expect?

Comment: it does. I'll upload a second edit because I got it to work for the most part but there is one thing I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, I changed your userEmail assignment and it's working:

```
%let emailUsername =        psamson6;
%let email =                %unquote(%str(&emailUsername.@gmail.com));
%let sasProgram =           %scan(&sysparm,2,+);
%let todayDate = %sysfunc(today(),MMDDYYS10.);
%let timeNow = %sysfunc(time(),TIMEAMPM.);


FILENAME mail
    EMAIL TO=%unquote(%str(%'&email.%'))
    SUBJECT='SAS Job Complete: &todayDate. on &timeNow.' 
    CONTENT_TYPE="text/html";



DATA _NULL_;
    file mail;
    PUT "<body>";
    PUT "<p>Hello,</p>";
    PUT "<p>This is an email confirming that your SAS program [&sasProgram..sas] has successfully ran and finished.</p>";
    PUT "<p>- Creators of the SAS Program</p>";
    PUT "</body>";
Run;
```